# Closing of 'career vs carrier'

Tags: discussion

The question '[career vs carrier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41106/career-vs-carrier-closed)' was closed as general reference.

Though a reference would show that they are pronounced the same, I don't know of any reference that shows that they **are** pronounced the same in Indian English. And I think that is a useful part of the question.

I think it should be reopened.

---

Edit:
I find the -underlying- question interesting, but on the surface it is poorly directed, working with uninformed assumptions (and I was uninformed about the Indian pronunciation). I think this is a problem, for me at least, of wanting to edit the question radically, but not for fear of altering the OP's intent radically also. But then I'm not sure I could reword it to not still be 'general reference': look up the pronunciation of the two  and you'll see that (in standard dictionaries at least) they are different.

---

Edit #2:
I understand the given reasons for closing. But...the existence of that phenomenon, the nonstandard pronunciation, is very interesting (whether organic or deliberate). And closing to me means 'that question should not have been asked' (or not asked that particular way). And I think there was something in that question that should have been asked/made public. And sometimes it is difficult to ask the question well without already knowing the answer.

Comment: As I commented on that question, this is a fake explanation someone has given to cover up BAD Pronunciation. Indians are **not** taught to pronounce car-*rear* as *caarr*ier but a lot of them do. A lot of us do pronounce it correctly as well - and it is not incorrectly pronounced on English news in India (for example). Just seems to be something some people have picked up - and funnily - try to justify.

Comment: Closing doesn't mean *that question should not have been asked*. It **means** no more answers can be added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question asked "what are the dialectical differences that make *career* and *carrier* homophones in Indian English, but not in other dialects?" then it would probably be worthy of staying open.

Comment: +1 because then it *would*. But the actual question never even *mentioned* the homophony, so it would have been a totally different question anyway. Incidentally, I think the reason is more to do with stress/cadence in Indian English than with the final *-ier / -eer*.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that some people (esp. Indians) might pronounce the two words the same (or nearly so) was only peripheral to the question as asked.

The OP there specifically made a case for wanting "carrier" to have a similar meaning to "career" because a career "carries" one through life.

The first answer given (by @Hugo) clearly indicated which word OP *should* be using, and I see no reason to reopen in hopes of a better one than that.

Any further discussion on the merits of OP's case for his own idiosyncratic (and incorrect) interpretation of *carrier* would be just that - discussion. I see no reason to reopen in order to encourage that discussion, which in any case is not prevented by the current "closed" status.